# Exclude anchor by title attribute. - Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm loading wordpress pages dynamically using ajax. It fires properly but I need to exclude a specific  anchor.

```
<a href="http://store.myurl.com" target="_blank" title="Store">Store</a>
```

I thought using .not() would work like so

```
$('a').not('a[title=Store]').live('click',function() {
```

But that breaks the whole thing.

If I use `$('a').live('click',function() {` it fires properly.

*p.s. I can't change the anchor output like ad an ID or a Class.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `:not` selector instead:

```
$('a:not([title="Store"])').live('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the mandatory quotes on the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
try

```
$('a:not(a[title="Store"])').live('click',function()
```

edit:
the live is not going to bind against elements returned by a filter (as `.not()`), you need a selector to match against when `.live()` resolves in body (where it is binded). so you need to use the `:not` selector, plus using the quotes for the attribute selector

Answer (score 2):

Does the attribute selector work without quotes?  I would use

```
$('a').not('a[title="Store"]').live('click',function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('a').not('[title=Store]').live('click',function() {
```

(I removed the letter "a" before "[title=Store]")